# When Uninstalling the previous Wix installer using NSIS it is taking longer time and the application title bar is showing "Not Responding"

Tags: wix, nsis

I migrated my software from Wix installer to NSIS. Upon installing the new version of my software, I first needed to uninstall the previous Wix package (If it is present).

From the NSIS installer, in the "Welcome" screen When clicked on "Next" I am checking the previous Wix package and if it is present uninstalling it. Below is my code snippet:

```
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE RemovePrevVerFunction

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Function RemovePrevVerFunction
ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\EMR\3.01.00" "InstallPath"
${If} $R0 != ""
MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "EMR 3.01.00 is already installed. Remove the pervious version?" IDOK uninst
Abort
uninst:
ExecWait '"MsiExec.exe" /X{8ED262EE-FC73-47A9-BB86-D92223246881} /qn'   ; /x is to uninstall and /qn is to uninstall it silently
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

With the above code I am able to uninstall the previous version. But I need to do few more things.

1. While uninstalling it is taking longer time and also Welcome screen becomes "Not Responding" but finally it is completing the uninstallation process. 
   Is there any way to uninstall it without becoming not responding?
2. I wanted to show the progress while uninstalling so that the end user knows that the uninstallation is going on. For that i removed "/qn" (silent uninstallation), if I remove "/qn" it is showing the progress but it is popping up one more message box "Are you sure you want to uninstall this product?" (Might be it is from the previous wix installer). Is there any way to show the progress without showing the message box "Are you sure you want to uninstall this product?"

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `/qb!` as parameter.

This should work, because parameter `/qb` display basic UI with no modal dialog boxes and additionally `/qb!` means, that you can't cancel uninstall process.

More information about it, you can find [here](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html) .

Greetings

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. Plus "try" does not really suggests you have a definitive answer. Why don't you just edit your answer and elaborate on how this solves the issue?